# Sketch Widget in JavaScript API for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any way to extract the coordinates of the vertices of the graphics drawn using sketch widget? I want to use those coordinates to generate a kml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to listen to `create` event of the widget. Check this example I made for you, it can guide you,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Sketch Feature Coords</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      require([
        "esri/widgets/Sketch",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/views/MapView"
      ], function(Sketch, Map, GraphicsLayer, MapView) {
        const layer = new GraphicsLayer();
        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets",
          layers: [layer]
        });
        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 5,
          center: [90, 45]
        });
        const sketch = new Sketch({
          layer: layer,
          view: view,
          // graphic will be selected as soon as it is created
          creationMode: "update"
        });
        view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");
        sketch.on("create", function(event) {
          // check if the create event's state has changed to complete indicating
          // the graphic create operation is completed.
          if (event.state === "complete") {
            const geom = event.graphic.geometry;
            // check type of geometry and print the coordinates
            switch (geom.type) {
              case 'point':
                console.log(`point: [${geom.x},${geom.y}]`);
                break;
              case 'polyline':
                console.log(`paths: ${geom.paths}`);
                break;
              case 'polygon':
                console.log(`rings: ${geom.rings}`);
                break;
              default:
                console.log(geom);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```